# R caret install error

Tags: r, r-caret

```
library(caret)
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  object 'vI' not found
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘caret’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’
```

I tried everything from re-installing R to deleting all the library folder but nothing helps.

Comment: I've never seen that. Showing the results of `sessionInfo()` would be a big help. Also, it's a bad idea to delete the library folder.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you need to install package lattice and ggplot2. Then install the caret package.
or, You can use the devtools library for installing the caret package.

```
    install.packages("devtools")
    library(devtools)
    install_cran("caret")
```

Comment: use this: install_cran("caret" , force=T)